# Make a file-type a drop target, but only when drag originates from same directory

Tags: shell, winapi, directory, drag-and-drop

I was experimenting with creating a drag-and-drop handler shell extension for certain file types, and I was wondering if you can implement a drag-and-drop handler where the drop target will only light up (indicating the possibility of dropping) when the drag originates from the same directory.  I know that in the handler logic, you can determine whether the drag target and drop target are within the same directory (it looks like `IFolderView2::IsMoveInSameFolder` might be used for that purpose) to determine whether the drag and drop should succeed. But I was wondering if it's possible to have the target only light up in the first place when the drag originates from the same directory.  Thank you for any input.

Comment: No you have no control over this. Explorer will highlight the target file if a drop handler is registered for it. The only thing you can control is the cursor indicating the outcome of the drop.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.